# avoiding loops on split strings in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, performance

My current DATE variable has entries like "Wednesday 01/01/86"
I am trying to split days from dates and put them separately into two variables.
My current code works but it has loops and may not be very efficient when dealing with large data. Any thoughts on improvement?

```
result$DATE <- as.character(result$DATE) ## cast DATE into character

new_DATE <- strsplit(result$DATE, " ") ## split days from dates

## store days and dates separately into two new variables
for(i in 1:length(result$DATE)) {
result$GAMEDATE[i] <- new_DATE[[i]][2]
result$GAMEDOW[i] <- new_DATE[[i]][1]
}
```

Comment: The primary mistake you've made in terms of performance is not the use of a loop, per se, but that you appear to be growing objects in the loop, rather than filling pre-allocated one. (It appears so anyway, hard to tell from your partial code.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `strsplit`

```
> dates <- c("Wednesday 01/01/86", "Thursday 02/01/86", "Friday 03/01/86")
> do.call(rbind, strsplit(dates, " ") )
     [,1]        [,2]      
[1,] "Wednesday" "01/01/86"
[2,] "Thursday"  "02/01/86"
[3,] "Friday"    "03/01/86"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(stringr)
> str_split_fixed("Wednesday 01/01/86",' ',2)
     [,1]        [,2]      
[1,] "Wednesday" "01/01/86"
```

Comment: `colsplit` in **reshape2** is a handy extension of this (it actually just calls `str_split_fixed` and names the results nicely).

Answer (score 0):

You can `sapply` though the output from `strsplit`, but you are better off just using the Date class:

```
(x <- as.Date(c("Wednesday 01/01/86","Friday 03/01/86"), "%A %d/%m/%y"))
[1] "1986-01-01" "1986-01-03"
```

You can then format to however you desire:

```
format(x,"%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "01/01/1986" "03/01/1986"
```

Both of these functions are vectorised and therefore will be fast.